# Getting different session ID's in servlet doFilter and spring security's ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security

I am using spring security to authenticate users and after that I am using ApplicationListener interface to put the users data in session after successful event. like this,

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LoggedUserListener implements
ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

@Autowired
private HttpSession session;

@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {

String name = event.getAuthentication().getName();//user.getUsername()

UserMaster userMaster = userDao.findByUserName(name);

System.out.println("Inside onApplicationEvent Session id is "+request.getSession().getId());

request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1 * 60 * 60);

 setSessionDataForUser(request.getSession(), userMaster);

}
```

where  setSessionDataForUser is custom method which adds users data in the given session.
I am having a authentication class which implements the filer interface for authenticating all requests coming from user after successful login. like this,

```
    public class Authentication implements Filter {

    final static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(Authentication.class);

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
System.out.println("Inside doFilter Session ID is "+httpRequest.getSession().getId());
}
```

The above is configured in web.xml as follows,

```
<session-config>
<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
<filter>
    <filter-name>authentication</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.lms.utils.Authentication</filter-class>
</filter>
```

However why am I getting different session ID's from both classes, actually I am writing a logic on the session ID's, so I require the session ID's in ApplicationListener and authentication class to be the same once user logged in.
The session ID I get in AuthenticationSuccessEvent is different from doFilter method of authentication class. Or is it because that for tomcat(server for login) a separate session ID is created and for all request after login i.e. request form angular IDE server a separate session ID is generated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the AuthenticationSuccessHandler in spring security and I got the new session. What was happening is that call to ApplicationListener on success event gets called early before spring security creates a new session. But after implementing the AuthenticationSuccessHandler I got the new session which spring security creates upon successful login.

Comment: Just experienced this problem, which is due to the session fixation protection strategy implemented by default by Spring Security. Another solution is to listen for `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` instead of `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and retrieve the session id with `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getSessionId()`, because the former is fired later than the latter, after the session id change has been performed.